# State of HTML5 in mobile browsers

Tags: database, browser, html, mobile, storage

What is the state of HTML 5 on the mobile browser ? I'm particularly interested in the offline storage possibilities (localStorage, Database storage with SQLish interface).

- **Android > 2.0**, database storage available (what about 1.6?)
- **iOS > 3**, database storage available
- **Blackberry** Webkit based browser ? database already available? In which version ?
- **WP7**, the browser seems to be a mix of IE7-8. No offline storage available I guess ?
- **Symbian**, It seems that QT (>=4.7) based Symbian application have access to Web Storage via QTWebkit http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qtwebkit.html Any idea how is it supported in the builtin browser ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find your answer here http://caniuse.com/ under Web Storage, it's the most complete list I have seen so far. I will update this answer if I find something more detailed.

Comment: Blackberry browser seems to support database storage as well. At least for version >=6. Don't know about previous versions. http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/18446/DOM_Storage_Objects_1180984_11.jsp

Comment: BB supports it only from >6 AFAIK.

Comment: Good article about the state of Nokia Browsers: http://yiibu.com/articles/practical-guide-to-nokia-browsers/

Answer (score 0):

You can find all these information at http://www.html5test.com. Not only webstorage api you can check all api's support